# What is RandomSearchCV and GridSearchCV?

Tags: machine-learning

I am doing logistic regression project. While doing so i came accross above concepts. So what is randomsearchCV and gridsearchCV ?

Comment: which libraries are you using? these seems to be sklearn classes, but please include this in the question if it is the case. also give some context so that the answerer knows what level to give the reply at. e.g. are you comfortable with the cross validation concepts? if you are learning from a book or home page - what resource are you using? where did you stumble upon the concepts etc. I'll write a short answer, but if you update the question I might edit my answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions and not a tutorial service; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean the classes of cross validation (CV) strategies as used in sklearn.

Cross validation is a method for evaluating models. One well known use case is to evaluate what set of hyper parameters to use in a model, such as a learning rate in gradient descents.

To find the optimal hyperparameters, we take a set of candidate hyper parameters, train models for all of these and compare their fitness via cross validation. Finally we select the hyperparameters that gave the best CV score.

#### Randomized Search Cross Validation

documentation at: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html

In short, this uses a random set of hyperparameters. Useful when there are many hyperparameters, so the search space is large. Can be used if you have a prior belief on what the hyperparameters should be.

#### Grid Search Cross Validation

documentation at: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Creates a grid over the search space and evaluates the model for all of the possible hyperparameters in the space. Good in the sense that it is simple and exhaustive. On the minus side, it may be prohibitively expensive in computation time if the search space is large (e.g. very many hyper parameters).